# GoogleMap V2 in fragment stops working properly at fragment reload

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a DrawerLayout with two fragments and one of them has a GoogleMap. At launch the map works as it should. But if i switch to the second fragment and the nswitch back to the first, or if an orientation change happens the map loses its "zoom to my location" button at the upper right corner of the map and it doesn't show my location with the blue dot and the accuracy radius. But I can still shows the map  and I can zoom in and out with mu fingers. Am I doing something wrong in my code? How can I fix this?

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList; 
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle; 
    public static FragmentManager mapFragmentManager;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mapFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

home fragment

```
public  class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    public HomeFragment() { }
    private View view;
    public static GoogleMap mMap;
    static LocationManager locationManager;
    Context con;
    static Double latitude;
    static Double longitude;
    boolean gotCategories=false;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) { return null;  }

        if(view==null){ 
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        }
        con = getActivity();


        setUpMapIfNeeded(); 

        return view;
    }

    public static void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((MapFragment) MainActivity.mapFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         setUpMapIfNeeded(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();
        try{MainActivity.mapFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(MainActivity.mapFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).commit();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like usual I figured out the answer just right after I posted the question...
In the onDestroyView I added the mMap=null; line...So now the the setUpMapIfNeeded function will run again and instantiate the map again and will be good as new. Hope this helps someone

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroyView();
        try{MainActivity.mapFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(MainActivity.mapFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).commit();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        mMap = null;
    }
```